# Etterfilter file-contents injection

Tags: tools, sniffer, injection

On the [`etterfilter(8)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/etterfilter), there is a section about the `inject()` function, which takes the contents of a file and injects it in a packet, or as its own packet when coupled with `drop()`:

> **inject(*what*)**
>
> this function injects the content of the file 'what' after the
>   packet being processed. It always injects in DATA.data. You can use it
>   to replace the entire packet with a fake one using the drop() function
>   right before the inject() command. In that case the filtering engine
>   will drop the current packet and inject the fake one.
>
> example:
>    inject("./fake_packet")

However, there is no documentation anywhere I have looked to speak to what *type* of file is expected by this function. ([Another user on a BackTrack Linux forum had the same question.](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=50662))

What type of file does `etterfilter`'s `inject()` function take? PCAP? Plain text? Another file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised [Issue #576](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/issues/576) on the [`ettercap` GitHub repository](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap) for clarification. The official response is that `ettercap` will inject the raw contents of any file into a packet (or into its own packet, if used in conjunction with the `drop()` command).

It does not require any particular file format.